# Changing STI types gets confused

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

```
class SubA < Base
end

class SubB < Base
  belongs_to :foo
  validates :foo, presence: true
end

copy = sub_a.dup.becomes SubB
copy.type = SubB.sti_name
copy.save!
```

Upon save, I get:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<SubA:0x007faa7b64abb8>>
```

If I remove the validation, the error goes away. Why is ActiveRecord calling validation for SubB but then thinking it's still a SubA? Bug maybe?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://wegowise.github.io/blog/2013/05/09/rails-gotcha-saving-sti-records/

Comment: I didn't understand. Your `SubA` and `SubB` inherent from `Base` How even they are ***STI***?

Comment: @Pavan In this example, ```Base``` inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.